# How to generate fixed cells row in django?

Tags: django

I am making Django app, where in page is a table with fixed number of cells (4 rows x 3 columns = 12 cells). It is ok, when there are 12 records on page - it fits nicely.

But when there are less records on page, I have to fill rest of the table with some predefined values (image and link to registration page).

I was searching for solution, but didn't find any. Does anybody have any ideas, how to do this?

Comment: Are you using Django's template language in your pages?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `QuerySet` to a list, pad it out with 12 dummy objects, then slice the list in the template to 12 items.

Answer (score 0):

In the dictionary of items you pass into the template from the view, include a variable for `range(12-len(your_records))`. Then, in the template, use the [for tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatetag-for) to loop over that variable, to add in the appropriate number of cells.